# Should i use relations or split the result

Tags: mysql, database

I'm creating a database that should contain coordinates, textsize, etc.

My first table looks like this

```
id, template_id, data_1, data_2, data_3, data_4, data_5, data_6, data_7, data_8
```

Every data_x field should have one of the following formats:

```
svg string;textsize
x;y;textheight;textwidth
x;y;imageheight;imagewidth
```

In the future more formats could be added

My question is, should i use those formats (and split them using eg PHP) or should i create a table for each format with relationships? What is the fastest/best practice?

I hope i explained myself well enough..

Comment: it depends on how you going to retrieve that data. if you need to do searches on those fields for example splitting and putting each column on another table is a better way

Comment: I only have to search for template_id an maybe id. I don't have to search the data_x fields

Comment: I know, i just don't know what method achieves the best performance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should not be storing these in separate columns.  You should have another table with one row per table1 id and another per data item.  It would have at least two columns:

- Table1Id
- DataColumn

It might also have an auto-incremented id, a sequential number to enumerate the ids and so on.

As for your question on how to store the data, that depends on how you are going to access them.  If the database is going to be blind to the contents, the you can store them all in a single field.  If you need to access them, then you might have to go to the next level and break things out into separate data tables, one for each type of value, that the above data column would refer to.

In any case, the more important change at this point is to put the "array" of data values into separate rows of another table.